# Model in the loop testing of C code in Matlab/Simulink

Tags: c, matlab, simulink

I make a distributed embedded application that will make use of several micro-controllers. The unit under control is a mechanical unit that I do not have, but I have a Simulink model of it. What are the possibilities to perform Model-in-the-loop testing of existing C code with minimum modification of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Integrating Existing C Functions into Simulink Models with the Legacy Code Tool](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/sfg/bq4g1es-1.html) offers an approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Real-Time Workshop](http://www.mathworks.com/products/rtw/) package for Simulink to generate C code that implements the mechanical model, and then compile the generated code along with your existing C code. So, the mechanical model would execute on the microcontroller, with the model's inputs and outputs being "connected" to the existing control code.

This would probably also need the [Embedded Coder](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/rtwembedded/) to be able to target the exact microcontroller architecture, and to produce more efficient code.